# How can I move the column with the values from one table to another in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, database-migration, hstore

I am want to move the column from one table to another.
So I've created 3 migrations:

1. AddNewColumnToTableTwo
2. MoveTheValuesFromTableOneToTableTwo
3. RemoveColumnFromTableOne

The 'thing' is - when I'm trying to run through all the records in the TableOne and update the TableTwo I see the error

```
TypeError: can't cast Columnname
```

P.S. Column type in both tables is **hstore**. Mayb this is the problem?

Comment: You should show your migrations too.

Comment: you probable need to do some casting to move the data. It would be useful to see you code.